# Does javascript create an execution context when we call web api functions?

Tags: javascript

I know that Javascript creates an execution context whenever I call a function that I wrote my self. For example:

```
function sum(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}

// new execution context will be created here:
sum()
```

However, what happens when I call web api functions like `setTimeOut() or fetch()`

Comment: Can you elaborate what exactly about `setTimeout()` makes it a "*web api [function]*"? What constitutes a "*web api [function]*"?

Comment: JavaScript uses a message pump, often known as cooperative multitasking.  So in a nutshell, things like timers / events etc get processed during the message / dispatch loop.

Comment: Yes. Sort of. As in "yes, they do", but since they likely call native code, that would also make another execution context elsewhere and the two aren't related. But why would having or not having an execution context make a difference?

Comment: Because I read that the call stack is a collection of execution context, so if setTimeOut is put there does that mean that js created an execution context for it? Excuse my ignorance I am just trying to learn this complex part of the language.

Comment: @esqew I mean code that is not part of javascript itself, but provided by browsers/nodejs like fetch and setTimeOut for example.

Comment: Yes, if you call, say `setTimeout` you would get an execution context, and then an entry on the callstack. But it's going to be resolved really quickly. Also, I'm still not sure what significance is there to this. I can't think of a reason you'd need that unless you're implementing a JS interpreter.

Comment: @VLAZ I am a very curious person and I am watching a course (Javascript - the hard parts v2) and this particular thing was not explained at all. I just want to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, all function call result in an execution context being created.

First of all, a tiny bit of background to make the subsequent explanations easier to understand. The spec talks about *internal slots*, these are abstract properties and methods that must be implemented. They aren't exposed to the outside, so you cannot use them directly, they for the implementation. The spec uses names that are in double square brackets, so for example [[Name]] - that refers to an internal slot called "name", for example.

With this in mind, let's also [clarify *what* is a function according to the spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots) (scroll to the bottom of section **6.1.7.2**):

> Table 7 summarizes additional essential internal methods that are supported by objects that may be called as functions. A *function object* is an object that supports the [[Call]] internal method. A constructor is an object that supports the [[Construct]] internal method. Every object that supports [[Construct]] must support [[Call]]; that is, every constructor must be a function object. Therefore, a constructor may also be referred to as a constructor function or constructor function object.

[Table 7](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#table-6) then describes more abstractly what [[Call]] and [[Construct]] do. At any rate, in short, it's an *object* that has the internal slot [[Call]].

Finally, we can have a look at [[Call]]. Quoting from the spec of chapter [**9.2 ECMAScript Function Objects**](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-ecmascript-function-objects) from chapter on [how [[Call]] should work](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-ecmascript-function-objects-call-thisargument-argumentslist):

> **9.2.1 [[Call]]** ( *thisArgument*, *argumentsList* )
>
> The [[Call]] internal method for an ECMAScript function object *F* is called with parameters *thisArgument* and *argumentsList*, a List of ECMAScript language values. The following steps are taken:
>
> 1. Assert: *F* is an ECMAScript function object.
> 2. If *F*.[[IsClassConstructor]] is **true**, throw a **TypeError** exception.
> 3. Let *callerContext* be the running execution context.
> 4. Let *calleeContext* be PrepareForOrdinaryCall(*F*, **undefined**).
> 5. Assert: *calleeContext* is now the running execution context.
> 6. Perform OrdinaryCallBindThis(*F*, *calleeContext*, *thisArgument*).
> 7. Let result be OrdinaryCallEvaluateBody(*F*, *argumentsList*).
> 8. Remove *calleeContext* from the execution context stack and restore *callerContext* as the running execution context.
> 9. If *result*.[[Type]] is `return`, return NormalCompletion(*result*.[[Value]]).
> 10. ReturnIfAbrupt(*result*).
> 11. Return NormalCompletion(**undefined**).

This is the full section and it applies to "normal" functions - those that are created by you or me. The full set of steps is actually irrelevant, I've only included it for completeness sake. The important part is step 4. - I will NOT quote the entirety of [PrepareForOrdinaryCall](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-prepareforordinarycall) because it's even more steps that don't really concern us, except these ones:

> 3. Let *calleeContext* be a new ECMAScript code execution context.
> 4. Push *calleeContext* onto the execution context stack; *calleeContext* is now the running execution context.
> 5. Return *calleeContext*.

So, in short, the function gets a new running execution context and that is put onto the stack. OK. Then at step 8. of [[Call]] the execution context is removed from the stack.

---

Now, let's have a look at section [**9.3 Built-in Function Objects**](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-built-in-function-objects). These are function objects that are provided by the environment and conform to the ECMAScript spec, things like `Object`, `Array`, `parseInt`, etc. The spec allows for these built-in functions to be implemented in the language itself (not necessarily JavaScript, remember that ECMAScript is the standard, so it would be the language *implementing* the standard) or as *provided* to the environment, which means potentially implemented in a different language. Still, the spec says:

> If a built-in function object is not implemented as an ECMAScript function it must provide [[Call]] and [[Construct]] internal methods that conform to the following definitions:

So, even if *provided*, the functions still have to provide a `[[Call]]` slot. And [here is the behaviour it should follow](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-built-in-function-objects-call-thisargument-argumentslist):

> **9.3.1** [[Call]] ( *thisArgument*, *argumentsList* )
>
> The [[Call]] internal method for a built-in function object *F* is called with parameters *thisArgument* and *argumentsList*, a List of ECMAScript language values. The following steps are taken:
>
> 1. Let *callerContext* be the running execution context.
> 2. If *callerContext* is not already suspended, suspend *callerContext*.
> 3. Let *calleeContext* be a new execution context.
> 4. Set the Function of *calleeContext* to *F*.
> 5. Let *calleeRealm* be *F*.[[Realm]].
> 6. Set the Realm of *calleeContext* to *calleeRealm*.
> 7. Set the ScriptOrModule of *calleeContext* to *F*.[[ScriptOrModule]].
> 8. Perform any necessary implementation-defined initialization of *calleeContext*.
> 9. Push *calleeContext* onto the execution context stack; *calleeContext* is now the running execution context.
> 10. Let *result* be the Completion Record that is the result of evaluating *F* in a manner that conforms to the specification of *F*.*thisArgument* is the **this** value, *argumentsList* provides the named parameters, and the NewTarget value is **undefined**.
> 11. Remove *calleeContext* from the execution context stack and restore *callerContext* as the running execution context.
> 12. Return *result*.

Again, the full set of steps is irrelevant. The important ones are 3., 9., and 11. - a new execution context is created, pushed to the stack, and finally removed. Step 8. allows for any implementation specific changes to the execution context.

---

These are the sections that prescribe how *running a function* should work. In both cases a new execution context is created, put on the stack and then removed once the function finishes.

For completeness, here is [chapter 8.3 . Execution Contexts](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#running-execution-context) if you want to know more about them. To summarise the important parts, there is at most one running execution context at any one point per thread. The *running execution stack* is also defined there as a LIFO structure with the *currently running execution context* on top.

Answer (score 1):

It creates an execution context. Lets take an example.

```
function run(){
  console.log("Hey");
  setTimeout(callback,2000);
}
run();
```

Here when run function is called an execution context is created. Now when console.log is called another execution context is created and put on top. It logs Hey to the console abd returns and thus the the context is removed from the stack. Now when setTimeout is called a context of setTimeout is also created which sets a timer of 2 secs in this case and the timer starts running in background. The setTimeout is then removed from the stack and as the two seconds are completed the callback function is sent to the message queue to wait for the stack to be empty. run function returns and is removed from the stack making the stack empty and then a context of callback function is created which does its job and returns. Finally the callback functions context is also removes from the stack.

Answer (score -1):

Javascript is block scoped, a block being anything in between 2 curly brackets `{}`.

If you have a function such as the one below it will have it's own scope separate from the global or window's scope.

```
function foo(){
   // Has a local scope contained to this function
   // When this function returns anything declared inside of here will be gone
   this.count = 2
}
foo()
console.log(this.count) // undefined
```

One way to get around this is by using the recently introduced arrow function which I think of as 'see through', meaning that it will take on the scope of the context in which it was called.

```
const foo = () => {
   // Has a global scope
   this.count = 2
}
foo()
console.log(this.count) // 2
```

With that, to determine the context when using functions like `setTimeout` and `fetch` really depends on what type of function is used and it's calling context

Comment: That's not what execution context is. An execution context *contains* an object environment record (what's normally referred to as "the context" and what the `this` keyword is) but it's not *the* execution context - it's part of it. Execution context is basically the memory allocated to this function alongside its place on the callstack and stuff.

Comment: Actually describes it pretty well, https://blog.bitsrc.io/understanding-execution-context-and-execution-stack-in-javascript-1c9ea8642dd0#6a83

Comment: I see what you're saying though, there are some pieces missing from my answer

Comment: And the article is still not talking about the *object environment record*, while you are. You were discussing `this` but not the actual execution context.